# CBC Encryption block size for 128 bit mode

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have a requirement to encrypt a string using AES with CBC in 128 bits

What do I need to set the block size to for this?

```
 var iv = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".ToByteArray();

 using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
 {
     myAes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

     // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
     byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(xml, myAes.Key, iv);

     // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
     string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, iv);

     //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
     Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", xml);
     Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
 }
```

Strangely enough my specification doesnt appear to cater for the IV

I havent been given anyway of telling the other side what the IV is so I think I will have to use a string of 0s, I thought it was 64 characters long so I have used the code above

Can someone help please?

Comment: The IV is a key and the same key must be used on the ecrypt and decrypt method.  The key cannot be empty.  Also you do not send the key with the message.  The key must be sent in a secure fashion between encrypt location and decrytp location.  Send the key with the message is like giving a thief the key to your house.

Comment: `ToByteArray()` is a terrible name for an extension method, because it doesn't tell the reader how it interprets the string or even if it performs regular decoding (from hex or base 64) or character encoding (and yes, `GetBytes` is terrible as well, Microsoft, you haven't learned since `atoi`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside any and all notion of security for a second that comes with sending the key/IV value or initializing them to static values...

Your code appears to come from the [AES documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-5.0) from Microsoft, so why not just stick with the generated IV value?

In case you absolutely want to set the IV yourself (shudders) you need to set it to a 128 bit value or 16 bytes. I don't know what your `String.ToByteArray()` code does exactly but if I were to hazard a guess, it probably converts the String to bytes using some encoding like UTF8 or ASCII. In either case, your IV array is going to be a lot more than 16 bytes in length. Just use something like `byte[] iv = new byte[16];` which will default initialize all slots to 0.

HOWEVER, since you mentioned I highly encourage you to double check how the key/IV are meant to be generated or conveyed to the other party.

Comment: Thanks I have been told that the key will be added to our key vault but no one has mentioned the iv. The code they use to decrypt in php is decrypted_string=openssl_decrypt($enc_file,"AES-128-CBC",$enc_password); which makes no sense as the iv is not provided

Comment: IV is an optional parameter for the https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php call. If it is not provided it defaults to an empty string. Maybe you can try to match that.
Although, it may be the wrong way of doing things: "Warning: openssl_encrypt(): Using an empty Initialization Vector (iv) is potentially insecure and not recommended in %s on line %d"
Meaning that the PHP with throw a warning level error if the IV argument is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

IV is not a key. IV stands for Initialization Vector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector. To generate an IV you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.generateiv?view=net-5.0

But your code already generates the IV and the KEY. Your code generates a 256 bits key and you want a 128-bit key. You can achieve that by adding

`myAes.KeySize = 128;` right after the `Aes.Create()`.

So applied to the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-5.0) you probably started from:

```
string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";

            // Create a new instance of the Aes
            // class.  This generates a new key and initialization
            // vector (IV).
            using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
            {
                myAes.KeySize = 128; //After this line key size will go to 16 bytes.

                // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
                string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
                Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
            }
```